# How to pass yaml file path to different modules and load configuration based on module

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have an yaml file example

```
logging:
   formatter:"abc" 
   handler:""
network:
   type:"udp"
udp:
   ip:"12.3.32.0"
   port:"20002"
```

when i start python program, i am passing config.yaml as command line args using argparse module, i am trying to load yaml file as below

**main.py**

```
def load_config(self):
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my yaml script')
        parser.add_argument('-f','--filepath', help='yaml file path')
        self.args = parser.parse_args()

        with open(args.filepath, 'r') as yamlStream:
            try:
                self.config = yaml.safe_load(yamlStream)
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print(exc)
```

and when i want to ready loggin i am passing

```
logger.load_config(self.config["logging"])
```

**logger.py**

```
def load_config(self, config):
        self.config = config
        logging.config.dictConfig(self.config)
```

but i do not want to load in the beginning when i start main, i want to pass only file path then load blocks of logging, network of yaml config whenever needed.

Comment: You're already putting `self.args.filepath` in the object of the class containing `load_config`, so you can access that in your modules.

Comment: example, if i want to load logging block, then i pass self.args.filepath, to the load_config method of logger class, logger.load_config(self.arg.filepath), and what should i implement inside load_config method,

Comment: right now my load_config(self, config): self.config = config
        logging.config.dictConfig(self.config)  which read only  logger.load_config(self.config["logging"]) from main

Comment: Well you'd just do the exact same thing you now do in the main `load_config`… just change loading into `self.config = yaml.safe_load(yamlStream)["logging"]`. If that doesn't solve your problem, maybe you should explain *why* you want to load the YAML file in each module.

Comment: i want to know what is right approach, there was some technical discussion on this with my colleague, my approach is load file in the main file, and pass node value to each module to read that specific node configuration example logging,

Comment: if go with my approach, i have one doubt, i have another node which is network, and type is udp, as soon as it read udp, it read sub configurataion of udp as well, from main to `network.py`  i called `createNetwork(congif["netowrk"] )` and `type = config['type']` i have to ready udp related info inside child class of network.py which is `udpnetwork.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with reading the whole YAML file and passing the whole structure to the modules. If you pass only the file name, you will read the whole YAML file multiple times which does not really make sense unless you expect it to change between reads.

For readability, you may want to define a class holding the configuration, like this:

```py
import argparse, yaml

class Config:
  def __init__(self, filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as yamlStream:
      raw = yaml.safe_load(yamlStream)
    self.logging, self.network, self.udp = raw["logging"], raw["network"], raw["udp"]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my yaml script')
parser.add_argument('-f','--filepath', help='yaml file path')
args = parser.parse_args()
config = Config(args.filepath)
```

Initializing the logger would look like

```py
# called with the Config object, i.e. logger.load_config(config)
def load_config(self, config):
  # do you really need to store this?
  self.config = config
  # access the relevant section
  logging.config.dictConfig(config.logging)
```

By passing the main config object around, you can easily access other sections as you describe in the comments.

Comment: Thank you it worked, my understanding was inside network node we have `type: udp` and this `udp` has another node `udp: ip and port` when we access network type it should give udp node as well, as `udp is mapped to type`, so we have some thing like this in yaml ? or we should access via config['udp'] only ?

Comment: The `"udp"` value in `network` is completely independent of the top-level `udp` key. I don't completely understand what you're asking, moreover I am unsure why you have that top-level `udp` node in the first place when you could just put `ip` and `port` into `network` below `type`.

Comment: because, we are creating network factory object using factory patters, which inherits UDPNetwork and TCPNetwork, Network factory class gives only which network has to be created, now UDP later may be other networks, once NF gives UDP object we pass udp related information to UDPNetwork class to create udp socket information.